# Cannot access class in web application when deployed to IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

**What I’m trying to do**: I’m developing an test ASP.Net Web Application. I’m building it using VS2017. I’m trying to deploy it to an IIS server that hosts Intranet site and content.I have a simple class with a void function and try to call that from the Webform.

**The problem**: When I run that code in VS debug it compiles and runs Ok. However, when I deploy it to the ISS server it will not work

**What I have done**: I have made sure the Class Build action is set to Compile. I have changed the framework from 4.6 to 4.0. I have tried publishing using the VS feature. I have tried just copying everything in the source folder directly to wwwroot folder.

WebForm:

```
using System;    
namespace Efile {
    public partial class efile : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test();
        }
        public void test()
        {
            Classy1 test1 = new Classy1();
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
using System;
namespace Efile
{
    public  class Classy1
    {
        public void testy()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Source Error:

```
Line 18:         public void test()
Line 19:         {
Line 20:             Classy1 test1 = new Classy1();
Line 21:         }
Line 22:     }


Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestSite\efile.aspx.cs    Line: 20
```

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Classy1'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Why would you expect that to make any difference when they're in the same namespace?

Comment: Did you deploy all the DLL's for your application? What does your deployment process look like?

Comment: Is this an "ASP.NET Web Application Project" or an "ASP.NET Website"? Do you have a directory named `App_Code` in your project?